# How to solve for this inverse question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inverse, inverse-function, word-problem

```
The time taken to complete a school project is inversely proportional to the number of students involved. 
A team of 5 students can complete the project in 6 weeks.
b) Suppose that 4 weeks into the project, one of the students left the team. 
   The remaining students decide to continue with the project by themselves. 
   Calculate the number of days needed to complete the project in this case.
```

**My working:**
$$y=\frac{k}{x}$$
**From the question,** $$k=210$$
**So for 5 students, it would take 42 days to complete the project.**

**So for 4 students, it would take 52.5 days to complete the project.**

**From the question, (into week 4), so it would be 21 days completed for 5 students.**

**The remaining days would be:**

```
21 days + Days of 4 students
```

The difference between 1 Student is :
$$52.5-42=10.5 days $$

**How to go on from here?? I'm confused to find the days to complete the project since the number of days depend on the number of students involve..**

Comment: After $4$ weeks with $5$ students, the project is $\frac23$ complete.  To complete the remaining $\frac13$, it will take $4$ students $\frac{52.5}3$ days

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted "4 weeks into the project, one of the students left the team"

to mean that one student left after $4$ weeks.

After $4$ weeks with $5$ students, the project is $\frac23$ complete.

To complete the remaining $\frac13$, it will take $4$ students $\frac{52.5}3$ days.